# How to change the order of input method

Tags: macos, text-input

I am using **OS X 10.8**

I wish I could change the order of **input method**.

How do I do that?

Comment: This is ridiculous, 10 years no answer! Apparently no solution :-((

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To setup input order (taken from [here](http://sanziro.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-keyboard-shortcuts-to-easily-switch-between-language-input-methods-in-mac-os-x.html)):

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Click on Language & Text and select Input Sources Tab
3. Select language which have multiple input orders like Chinese for example
4. Whilst highlighted click on Keyboard Shortcuts button to the right
5. Check "Select the previous input source" and "Select next source in input menu"
6. Now click on the keyboard shortcut for both the options as mentioned in point 5 and enter your convenient options
7. you can now use those 2 new setup shortcuts to easily cycle between input sources.

Comment: Links tend to break over time, that's why it would help if you could summarize the content of the linked article in your answer.

Comment: I have done the changes. Thank you for formatting it properly. I have voted you up

Comment: Google cached link: (I hope this doesn't break over time)
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:o0tMQNBXHgQJ:https://sanziro.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-keyboard-shortcuts-to-easily-switch-between-language-input-methods-in-mac-os-x.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: This answer is good, but it doesn't answer what the OP asked for. This allows to change inputs but they're always in an arbitrary order established by the OS.

Comment: @Petruza, while I agree it doesn't answer the question, I note that OP accepted it as the answer.  (Or is it possible for someone else to do so?)